# How to quote a quote

Tags: punctuation

If I am citing a phrase that looks like this:

> She said "That's fun!"

and I only want the `"That's fun!"` part, should I write it like this:

> "'That's fun!'"

this:

> 'That's fun!'

or this:

> "That's fun!"

Answer (score 1):

Nested quotation marks (such as "'That's fun!'") are only used when you are quoting someone who is quoting someone else.

Your other two choices ('That's fun!' and "That's fun!") are both OK in the absence of a style guide.  Most people use double quotes ("That's fun!") for most quotations, and single quotes when necessary.  Nested quotes tend to alternate double quotes with single quotes, with the double quotes on the outside.